# GnuCash - Help Buttons Not Working

Tags: linux, gnucash

**GnuCash 2.6.15** - Debian Stretch

`gnucash-docs` and `yelp` packages installed.

While in **GnuCash**, when I activate a sub-window "Help" button (e.g. as seen by clicking **Edit** -> **Find...** -> **Help**), the mouse pointer changes from a pointer icon to the active processing icon for about 15 seconds. It then changes back to a pointer icon without any other action. No help dialog is created.

However, when clicking (on the main toolbar menu) **Help** -> **Tutorial and Concepts Guide**, said guide comes up as is should!

**I suspect I may be missing a package, but which one?**